# NOT NULL constraint failed: studentapp_studentproject.project_owner_id

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

Модель:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models


def validate_int(value):
    if value < 1 or value > 10:
        raise ValidationError('%s is not an correct number (1 <= value <= 10)' % value)

class StudentProject(models.Model):
    project_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_date = models.DateTimeField('project date')
    project_relevance = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_int])
    project_feasibility = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_int])
    project_originality = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_int])
    project_elaborate = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_int])
    project_report_quality = models.IntegerField(validators=[validate_int])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_title
```

сериализатор:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import StudentProject, StudentForum

class StudentProjectListPageSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    project_owner = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    project_title = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    project_date = serializers.DateTimeField('project date')
    project_relevance = serializers.IntegerField()
    project_feasibility = serializers.IntegerField()
    project_originality = serializers.IntegerField()
    project_elaborate = serializers.IntegerField()
    project_report_quality = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return StudentProject.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

apiviews:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .models import StudentProject, StudentForum
from .serializers import StudentProjectListPageSerializer, StudentForumListPageSerializer


@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def studentproject_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        studentprojects = StudentProject.objects.all()
        serializer = StudentProjectListPageSerializer(studentprojects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = StudentProjectListPageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            studentproject = serializer.save()
            return Response(StudentProjectListPageSerializer(studentproject).data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

ошибка:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: studentapp_studentproject.project_owner_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка говорит сама за себя: туда, куда нельзя писать NULL значения (`project_owner`), вы пытаетесь его записать.